Prevent WebApplicationFactory from passing any arguments to the Program.Main method
I have an ASP.Net application where the Program.Main method is doing this:
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var parserResult = CommandLine.Parser.Default.ParseArguments<CommandLineOptions>(args);
        if (parserResult.Errors.Any())
            return;

        // do all the rest of the initialization
    }
}

To make sure things are working properly, I'm trying to do integration tests by using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory for this Program class with code like this:
var client = _factory
    .WithWebHostBuilder(
        builder =>
        {
            builder.ConfigureTestServices(
                services =>
                {
                    services.AddScoped(sp => mockRepository.Object);
                }
            );
        }
    )
    .CreateClient();
const string url = $"/some/path/to/test";

var response = await client.GetAsync(url);

response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // Status Code 200-299

The default CommandLine.Parser.Default instance is configured to error out on command line parameters that it does not know about which is something I'd like to keep.
Sadly in the context of the test code above, the Program.Main method receives an array of multiple parameters, like so:
--ENV_VAR=1234
--environment=Development
--contentRoot=/path/to/my/app
--applicationName=My.App.WebApi

The first is named as an environment variable defined on the machine while the others are apparently coming "out of the blue".
I looked around for an explanation as to why I get those arguments and found that line in the sources for AspNet core but I can't figure out a solution to get rid of any configuration in the host configuration.
I have tried to add the following code in the WithWebHostBuilder lambda:
            builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration(
                (context, configurationBuilder) =>
                {
                    configurationBuilder.Sources.Clear();
                }
            );

but it did not change anything, which is even confirmed by the fact that a breakpoint on Sources.Clear() is not reached before Program.Main is called.
I also tried adding the following:
var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
builder.UseConfiguration(configurationBuilder.Build());

But despite the code being called, I still have arguments being given to Program.Main
For now I have disabled the "error on unknown parameter" option, but I'd really appreciate any suggestion as to how to prevent WebApplicationFactory from passing any arguments to the Program.Main method

One way of going about this would be to add these parameters to your CommandLineOptions class:
public class CommandLineOptions
{
    //Your command line definition here...

    //The following are added to support the issue (optional)
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    [Option("ENV_VAR")]
    public string EnvVar { get; set; }

    [Option("environment")]
    public string Environment { get; set; }

    [Option("contentRoot")]
    public string ContentRoot { get; set; }

    [Option("applicationName")]
    public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
}

This will prevent the errors and still work when these parameters are not present.
Another option would be to use the environment to tell you how to parse the arguments:
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var parserResult = GetCommandLineParseResult(args);
    
    if (parserResult.Errors.Any())
        return;

}

private static ParserResult<object> GetCommandLineParseResult(string[] args)
{
    var environment = args.FirstOrDefault(a => a == "--environment");
    ParserResult<object> parserResult;
    switch (environment)
    {
        case "development":
            parserResult = CommandLine.Parser.Default.ParseArguments(args, typeof(TestCommandLineOptions));
            break;
        case null:                    
            parserResult = CommandLine.Parser.Default.ParseArguments(args, typeof(CommandLineOptions));
            break;
        default:
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Environment not supported: {environment}");
    }
    return parserResult;
}    

public class TestCommandLineOptions : CommandLineOptions
{
    [Option("ENV_VAR")]
    public string EnvVar { get; set; }

    [Option("environment")]
    public string Environment { get; set; }

    [Option("contentRoot")]
    public string ContentRoot { get; set; }

    [Option("applicationName")]
    public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
}

Your original CommandLineOptions class will remain clean and you'll use a derived class (TestCommandLineOptions) for testing scenarios.
Bottom line is, you are making certain assumptions about the incoming parameters so you can't have it both ways. Either you enforce it, or you don't.
If you can't control the parameters passed on to your app, then ignoring unknown ones seems fairly reasonable to me. Zero harm done so why not? Instead of using the default Parser instance options (error on unknown), simply configure it to ignore them. Problem solved.

Yes, I tried that as well, but I don't have any control on the CI worker and the environment variables that it defines. Some of these vars are even totally unrelated to the project and it feels wrong to add them to my options class.

@OBones I agree that it doesn't seem like a good idea, but it's one way of doing it if you want to keep the unknown parameter validation. Please read my updated answer. It feels to me like the obvious way to go is to just ignore unknown parameters.

Thanks, I did come up with such a way to decide on what options to use for the parser, but that's yet another workaround.
I know that erroring out on unknown parameters is not really a "usual" situation but that's what my client has asked for...

@OBones everything is going to be a workaround if you have conflicting requirements. You have to choose your battles. Right now, it seems to me like you are drowning in a glass of water. Talk to your customer and explain that he can't have it both ways.
